# How can I close the search toggle for vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know this question's been asked before ([How to close the search toggle for vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50078372/how-to-close-the-search-toggle-for-vscode)) but I was wondering if anything had been changed and if someone could tailor their response to me

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press ESC on the keyboard or click the X in the far right of the dialog.

Comment: It was that esc. shortcut I was looking for - thank-you!